# Change parent class variable inside a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class like that in Android:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;
    private final Context CONTEXT = this;
    ...

    public void method()
    {
        vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                vehicles.add(new Vehicle());
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT);
                b.setMessage(vehicles.size());
                b.create().show();
                // b displays the correct size here
            }
        });
        t.start();
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT);
        b.setMessage(vehicles.size());
        b.create().show();
        // b displays 0 here
    }
}
```

my problem is that `vehicles` content changes only inside my thread (I've noticed that by putting an `AlertDialog` and display its size), but when my thread dies the changes aren't kept and `vehicles` has size 0 still.
I've tried to put `vehicles.add(new Vehicle())` statement inside the `runOnUiThread` method, but the size still remains at 0.

Comment: What if you put the variable as static? private static ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;

Comment: Your code is incomplete, atleast your current code throws `NullPointerException` as `vehicles` is not assigned with any object, then, where is the code that checks that the list is 0 or not? Post that here

Comment: Based on what you think "when thread dies the changes aren't kept and vehicles has size 0 still" ? In other words, where did you put your `AlertDialog` ?

Comment: Bad idea. Static mutable variables are Petri dishes for defects. What is your reasoning here? You should not just throw stuff at the wall in hopes that some will stick.

Comment: You decide between class or instance variables based on the concept you are looking for, not for solving any synchronization issue.

Comment: @javaguy
@GaëtanMaisse
I've changed the code: the `AlertDialog` inside the thread shows the correct size, but that outstide the thread displays 0

Comment: @Clyky where is the method in which you validate the size (modified by above thread) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of variable that are not kept but a Java thread execution order! With multiple threads code execution is not sequential anymore. In your example, there is no way to know if `AlertDialog` from `method` will be called before `Thread` `run` function (it looks like not).

Welcome to multithreading magic.

```
public void method() {
    vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            vehicles.add(new Vehicle());
        }
    });
    // Here you start the Thread 
    t.start();
    // But there is no guaranty that on this line the "run" function of the Thread has been called
    // And if it has not been called then vehicules is empty
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT);
    b.setMessage(vehicles.size());
    b.create().show();
    // b displays 0 here
}
```

Comment: ok, so what should I do to change also the `vehicles` of the main thread and not only the thread's one?

Comment: There is one and only one `vehicles` but `AlertDialog` just after `t.start` is called before `vehicles.add(new Vehicle());`

Comment: I don't know if that it's true.
If I put a breakpoint at the LAST `method`'s line and a watcher to see `vehicles`, also the debugger shows that `vehicles` has size of 0.
I also tried a `t.join()`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on last `method`'s line and one on `vehicles.add(new Vehicle());` line, which one is called first?

Comment: as you say, the last one (after `t.start()`) is called, and the breakpoint inside the thread is never called.
also debugging with multithreading makes me crazy lol

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility ;)

Answer (score 0):

My preference with something like this is to create a listener interface that the parent class can implement.  It allows you to cleanly hand off execution back to the parent original thread class, along with any objects.

Your main issue is timing, after the thread is kicked off, nothing has been added to the vector yet because it immediately executes it after starting the thread.  So, you can also add a "complete" method to indicate all vehicles have been added.

Create a class to represent your runnable thread, and create a "vehicledAdded(Vehicle vehicle)" that can be called on any listeners.

Something like this (this is off the cuff and not compiled, so it is probably chocked full of typos, but it'll get you close enough):

```
class MyParentClass implements VehicleListener {
  private Vector vehicles = new Vector();

  public MyParentClass() {
    VehicleAdderTask vat = new VehicleAdderTask();
    //add this class as a listener on the task
    vat.addVehicleListener(this);

    //kick the thread off
    Thread t = new Thread(vat);
    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void vehicleAdded(Vehicle v) {
    vehicles.add(v);
  } 

  @Override
  public void taskComplete() {
    //output your vehicle list
  }

}

class VehicleAdderTask implments Runnable {
  private List<VehicleListener> listeners = new ArrayList<VehicleListener>();
  public void addVehicleListener(VehicleListener vh) {
    listerners.add(vh);
  }

  public void run() { 
    while(somecondition) {
      Vehicle v = new Vehicle();

      //fire event ot indicate a new vehicle was added.
      for(VehicleListner vl: listeners) {
        vl.vehicleAdded(v);
      }
    }

    //fire task completed on all listeners 
    for(VehicleListner vl: listeners) {
      vl.taskComplete();
    }

  }
}

interface VehicleListener {   
  public void vehicleAdded(Vehicle v); 
  public void taskComplete();
}
```